# C# OOP acessing members of a class unity

Tags: c#, oop

To access members in c++ for example if you have a class dog
you first create an object

```
dog mydog;
```

then acess the object

```
mydog.breed="whatever";
```

in C# the syntax is

```
dog mydog=new dog();
```

and to access the variables

```
mydog.breed="whatever";
```

My question is howcome in unity this effect is achieved by
creating a static variable

```
public static dog mydog;
```

and then accessing it by putting the class name followed by the object name

```
dog.mydog.breed;
```

this is twisting my understanding of OOP and It would be great if someone could clarify.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Unity or C++ - that is entirely regular C# syntax for accessing a member via a static variable. The variable would still have to be initialized to a non-null value somewhere though.

Comment: But howcome in unity coding this method for creating objects and manipulating them doesn't work?                                                                  dog mydog=new dog();


mydog.breed="whatever";

Comment: @lolsharp: what "unity" do you mean?

Comment: I think the answer just hit me in the face like  a ton of bricks  its because in unity3d c# coding everything is in a class.

Comment: @lolsharp: It's absolutely fine to use `dog mydog = new dog(); mydog.breed="whatever";` in Unity, so long as that's within a method. (Although when I say "absolutely fine" I mean "it will work" - it violates just about all the .NET naming conventions...)

Comment: Thank you so much Jon Skeet :)